# Recursively wrapping a regular expression with given text

Tags: regex, linux, replace

For a given path, I wish to wrap a given regular expression in all files in that path or that path's sub-directories with some given text using standard Linux shell commands.

More specifically, wrap all my syslog commands with an assert command such as `syslog(LOG_INFO,json_encode($obj));` becomes `assert(syslog(LOG_INFO,json_encode($obj)));`.

I thought the following might work, but received `sed: -e expression #1, char 47: Invalid preceding regular expression` error.

```
sed -i -E "s/(?<=syslog\()(.*)(?=\);)/assert(syslog(\1));/" /path/to/somewhere
```

BACKUP INFO IN RESPONSE TO Wiktor Stribiżew's ANSWER

I've never used `sed` before.  Please confirm my understanding of your answer:

```
sed -i "s/syslog(\(.*\));/assert(syslog(\1));/g" /path/to/somewhere
```

- `-i` edit files in place.  One could first leave out to see on the screen what will be changed.
- `s`   substitute text
- The three `/`'s surrounding the pattern and replacement (i.e. `/pattern/replacement/`) are deliminator and can be any single character and not just `/`.
- `syslog(\(.*\));`  The pattern with one placeholder.  Uses escaped parentheses.
- `assert(syslog(\1));`  The replacement using escaped `1` (or `2`, `3`, etc) for replacement sub-strings.
- `g`  Replace all and not just the first match.

Would `sed -i "s/syslog(.*);/assert(&);/g" /path/to/somewhere` work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` patterns do not support lookarounds like `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)`.

You may use a capturing group/replacement backreference:

```
sed -i "s/syslog(\(.*\));/assert(syslog(\1));/g" /path/to/somewhere
```

The pattern is of BRE POSIX flavor (no `-E` option is passed), so to define a capturing group you need to use escaped parentheses, and unescaped ones will match literal parentheses.

**Details**

- `syslog(` - `syslog(` substring
- `\(.*\)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `);` - a `);` substring

The replacement is `assert(syslog(\1));`, that is, the match is replaced with `assert(syslog(`, the contents of Group 1, and then `));`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.  Never used `sed` before.  Please see my edited original question and confirm whether it is accurate.  Thanks

Comment: Also, will this just work on the single regular file `/path/to/somewhere`?  What if `/path/to/somewhere` was a directory and I wanted it to apply to all files in this and sub-directories?

Comment: Ah, how I see.  `find ~/test -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/syslog(\(.*\));/assert(syslog(\1));/g"`.  Still would like your comments on my edited question responding to your answer.

Comment: Not quite as it includes an extra `;`, but `sed -i "s/syslog(.*;);/assert(&);/g" ./test` seems to work.

Comment: I wanted to display the matches before executing my recursive solution, so left out the `-i` flag, but it displays all results.  Know how I can just show the matched lines before using in place editing?

Comment: @user1032531 Well, you mean to print matching *lines*, then use `grep` rather than `sed`. `grep 'syslog(.*);' myfile`

Answer (score 0):

If you need Perl-compatible regex constructs, you can use Perl (sic).

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=syslog\()(.*)(?=\);)/assert(syslog($1));/' /path/to/somewhere
```

Regardless of this specific solution I switched to single quotes on the assumption that you are on a Unix-ish platform. Backslashes inside double quotes are pesky (sometimes you need to double them, sometimes not).

Perl prefers `$1` over `\1` in the replacement pattern, though the latter will also technically work.

Comment: For your specific problem, the regex can easily be refactored to an ERE or even BRE regex without lookbehinds etc. If your requirements are more complex than that, or you just don't feel up to learning the differences between the regex dialect you (apparently) know and a number of others, perhaps this can help.